# Was my last minute edit also not acceptable?

Tags: discussion

[What makes carbon the most important to making molecules biological? [on hold]](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30505/what-makes-carbon-the-most-important-to-making-molecules-biological?noredirect=1#comment50470_30505)

I made some last minute edits. I am unsure if the last minute edits were also not sufficient, or I was simply too late to recover the question. Was my last minute edit also not acceptable?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: As revised, I don't think your question is too bad, although it might be better suited to [chemistry.se]. Technically, an organic compound is simply one that is carbon-based, although for historical reasons certain classes are excluded, such as pure carbon (diamond, graphite, etc.), carbides, carbonates, cyanides, simple carbon oxides, carbon-containing alloys like steel - basically, it's arbitrary. It doesn't have to contain all the components of the classic CHONP group, just C and 1 other. You might want to clarify that part of your question.

Answer (score 6):

Your original question was impossible to answer, there are far too many possible definitions for "every biological molecule". Even if you could get some answer, it wouldn't really be useful.

Your edited question is a completely different one. From the timestamps it looks like the users that deleted your question probably didn't even see the changed version.

The question about why carbon is so important to biological molecules is probably a valid one. I suspect it is a duplicate, but I'm not sure if it was already asked here or on Chemistry.SE.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.